# JavaScript Debugger for Understanding Source Code

Tags: javascript

### Context

I am trying to understand the internals of a big, hairy JavaScript library.

I already have the un-minified version.

JavaScript's dynamic-ness is making it hard for me to guess what is happening by just reading the code.

I want something like gdb ... where I can "step" through each individual JavaScript function / line of code.

### Question:

What browser (Safari? Firefox? Chrome?) should I be using, and with what plugin?

Thanks!

Comment: I was actually thinking about w3m/lynx, haven't checked the state of their JavaScript support yet though. :-) [for the record, I love browsers with vim key bindings]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [Chrome Developer Tools](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/overview). A debugger and a profiler are included.

And when you just want to know what's inside an object, use console.log(obj) : you'll see its content in a property tree. As there are many tools, I suggest you completely read the official documentation : using them correctly really makes a *big* difference in your productivity.

A similar tool is now present in Firefox (you had to use Firebug before) but Chrome is more used, partly because of its more powerful js engine (V8).

IE starts to include such a toolset, but it's really poor and painful to use for now (I guess this will change).

Comment: And don't forget you can set breakpoints, step through the scripts, and use the 'immediates' console.

Comment: How is Chrome more powerful than Firebug?

Comment: @Pumbaa80 . I don't want to start a flame war on tool preferences, so I'll just change to say that Chrome is most used because of its more powerful V8 engine (nobody discuss this, I think).

Comment: I didn't mean to flame either. I just don't know. Haven't used Chrome in ages, only Firebug...

Comment: To be fair, they're now similar enough that you have to follow the news to see if one still has advantages. This is now a matter of preferences (and habits).

Comment: Did not realize "scripts" tab had a debugger built into it. I like.

Answer (score 1):

there is a developer tool in every modern browser these days. press `F12` OR `ctrl+shift+k` on the browser window to get one.

you can set breakpoints and use immediate console to analyse the code

Answer (score 0):

You could get [FireBug](http://getfirebug.com/javascript) for Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

For debugging i would use Firefox's Developer tools->Error console to check the errors first. Yes, i Use firebug for more advance debugging. But i solve most of my problems by looking at the error console.

“Simplicity is the ultimate sophistication.”
- Leonardo da Vinci